# React + CSS: Scrollable section inside another scrollable section getting me issues to get the footer in Mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scroll

Hope you can help me out here.

The thing is that I have a section, where I map components. This section has a vertical scroll. Outside this section, there's another components, like a map , navbar, footer, etc.
When I'm in **mobile**, I can scroll through all the components mapped, but when I got to the end of the section, I can't get to the footer or the pagination component.

To test this issue, [you can enter this site](https://www.welcome2ba.com/properties) and
try to scroll down all over and get to the pagination component **in a mobile**.

Sorry if I didn't explained it well, It's an annoying issue and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the inline style here:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12" style="height: 860px; overflow-y: scroll;">
```

Try removing the inline style and adding a class that you can apply the required styling to in a media query to target desktop.

So it could look something like (you can name the class to something more appropriate)

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12 scroll-fix">
```

css

```
    /* Reset for desktop */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
      .scroll-fix {
         height: 860px; 
         overflow-y: scroll;
      }
     }
```

Comment: That works!!!!!!! Definitely I missed that line. Thank you very much Walter!

Answer (score 0):

I tested here using my PC and my cellphone and worked well. Anyway, if the problem persists, try to create a bigger space between components with margin top/down and test again and check using different models of cellphone to see how it will look.

[Responsively App](https://responsively.app/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But in that app you can't reply the issue. I use my iPhone to navigate in that site and if I scroll down all over, I have to stop scrolling, then scroll again to get to the pagination or footer.

Comment: Make some tests using androids. If this is an issue related to iOS this link you help you: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/guidelines/overview